# How do I add my own scripts to the add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts') function?

Tags: javascript

The challenge is, when you connect your template to display a specific category, to completely clear the contents of a function `wp_head()`.

Perfectly done by the function `remove_all_actions('wp_head')`.

But after that I need to connect my own styles and scripts to it (previously cleaned).

Why doesn't this design work?

1) Delete all:

```
remove_all_actions('wp_head');
```

2) Add my own style file via a standard hook `'wp_enqueue_scripts'`:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  wp_enqueue_style('project-main', get_project_directory_url() .'/animals/styles.css', false, '0.0.0', 'all');
});
```

...has tried even so (, too, not works):

```
add_action('wp_head', function() {
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_style('project-main', get_project_directory_url() .'/animals/styles.css', false, '0.0.0', 'all');
  });
});
```

Please tell me how to clean the function `wp_head()` re-start adding your files via `'wp_enqueue_scripts'`?

Thank you!

Comment: You removed all of the actions from wp_head, one of those actions prints scripts and styles. You probably want to dequeue all other scripts and styles rather than disable the entire enqueue system.

Answer (score 0):

> You removed all of the actions from wp_head, one of those actions
>   prints scripts and styles. You probably want to dequeue all other
>   scripts and styles rather than disable the entire enqueue system.

Yes